# Response.Redirect Same Page RadioButtonList SelectedItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, radiobuttonlist, request.querystring

I'm trying to do a job filter for the list of jobs on our website. The filter for the job type is wrapped in an UpdatePanel and the button to apply the filters redirects back to the same page.

This is because I will be using the umbraco.library:RequestQueryString in the XSLT to populate the jobs list.

However, the querystring filter value doesn't seem to select the RadioButtonList. For example:

The page loads, but nothing happens because vt is null:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vt = Request.QueryString["vt"];

        if (vt != null)
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in rblVacancyType.Items)
            {
                if (li.Value == vt)
                {
                    li.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSearchFilters" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <p>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblVacancyType" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="all"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Permanent" Value="permanent"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Temporary" Value="temporary"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </p>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here's the button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibFilters" ImageUrl="~/images/buttons/filter-button.png" OnClick="ibApplyFilters_Click" runat="server" />
```

Here's the procedure:

```
protected void ibApplyFilters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/careers/join-us/?filters=true&vt=" + rblVacancyType.SelectedValue.ToString());  
    }
```

Yet when the page redirects the first time, nothing is selected, I click permanent, permanent gets selected. If I then select 'All' or 'Temporary' the selection doesn't change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make dropdown autopostback=true.

Comment: When you step through and debug. What does it do on the initial page load where nothing changes? Is it always passing through the right selected value on the Click?

Comment: No, I'm just doing that now. I've got a break point on the ibApplyFilters_Click, when clicked the first time it picks up the selected value, when I change and click it the second time, selected value stays the same. I've tried adding EnableViewState="false" to the RadioButtonList and the button to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the behavior (it works the first time) I believe this describes what's happening:

- MyPage.aspx (original load)
- Page controls initialized to default
- Page Load - No query string, no radio button selected

(user clicks button - causes postback)

- MyPage.aspx (postback)
- Page controls initialized to default
- Radio Button Set from ViewState
- Page Load - No query string, no radio button selected
- ButtonClick - uses radio button setting, does response redirect
- MyPage.aspx?VT=Permanent (load from redirect)
- Page controls initialized to default
- Page Load - Query string set, radio button selected

(user clicks button - causes postback)

- MyPage.aspx?VT=Permanent (postback)
- Page controls initialized to default
- Radio Button Set from ViewState
- Page Load - Query string set, radio button set to Permanent (Here is the problem)
- ButtonClick - uses radio button setting, does response redirect

I believe a simple (if !IsPostback) will fix things

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your assessment. The bit I wonder is not right that the button is not a post back - but a redirect. Surely the button should change the Response.Redirect to match what is selected on the RadioButtonList, then redirect, but it is this bit that doesn't appear to be happening.

Comment: Yep, the check for IsPostBack solved it, I'd negated it due to the redirect, but now I've looked at your breakdown I can see where it is going wrong - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like postback values being re-applied.  See this article on ASP.NET page lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx.

Values for controls are re-applied via postback after page_load.

Comment: Is this not a post back though? The button should Response.Redirect... no?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the strange nature of code + postbacks the **logic** in Mark's answer seems to be quite accurate, but the suggested fix did not work as I had tried that as a possible solution. The below is a modification, but as far as I could see it works. Give it a try, it might work out for you.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
         </asp:ScriptManager>

         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSearchFilters" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <p>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblVacancyType" runat="server"  
                            AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="all"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Permanent" Value="permanent"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Temporary" Value="temporary"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>

                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibFilters" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            Height="30px" OnClick="ibApplyFilters_Click" />
                    </p>
                </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>

</form>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ibFilters.PostBackUrl = "~/WebForm1.aspx?filters=true&vt=" + rblVacancyType.Text;
   string vt = Request.QueryString["vt"];    
}
```

**Important:**

The way this is set up, it will maintain your selection, update the filter parameters in the url on button push, and then assign vt the correct value to be used on filtering anything else on your page.

You must change out my "~/WebForm1.aspx?filters=true&vt=" for your url as well.

Comment: Hi KreepN, I tried your solution, but the PostBackUrl doesn't append the filters to the end of the search.

Comment: Assuming you pasted the code above, which does indeed differ from yours, due to changes I made, it does in fact append the filters. Sorry you had problems with it.